# UI components not getting completely displayed in NSIS ModernUI Custom pages

Tags: nsis

I am a beginner at working with NSIS and am trying to create a custom page. I have added a few components to the custom page as follows

```
    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 10 10u 80% 20u "Please provide configuration details."

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 10 30u 40% 10u "Check this box for input 1"
    ${NSD_CreateCheckBox} 280 30u 10% 10u ""

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 10 50u 40% 10u "Enter the details for input 2"
    ${NSD_CreateText} 10 60u 80% 10u ""

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 10 80u 40% 10u "Enter the details for input 3"
    ${NSD_CreateText} 10 90u 80% 10u ""

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 10 110u 40% 10u "Enter the details for input 4"
    ${NSD_CreateText} 10 120u 80% 10u ""

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 10 140u 40% 10u "5"
    ${NSD_CreateText} 10 150u 80% 10u ""
```

[image]

As evident, all the elements after element 4 are not getting displayed.
Can you please tell me what I might be doing wrong here and how can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not look like the stock UI! Where is the horizontal line above the buttons? Why is the branding text higher up than the buttons? If you are using a custom UI file or are changing the UI at run-time then please tell us...

Comment: The horizontal line above the buttons is not there on the default pages as well. For instance, I can not find them on ` !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY` either. I am not changing the layout of the dialog box, I am using the default one. I just add a function for custom page with the above code to the default dialog box design.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by adding the below command 
`System::Call 'user32::MoveWindow(i$ServiceInputDialog,i,i,i 670,i 400,FALSE)'`

Comment: Do you have any code in .onGuiInit or the previous pages that move the line and branding text?

Comment: No, I haven't changed any UI details using .onGuiInit. Just the above statement solved it. Just to tell you the context if it helps, we had an installer created using nsDialogs library and now we are moving it to ModernUI. So, to add custom page I still am using the same syntax as I used for nsDialogs and changing the code only on need basis.

Comment: If you post a full example script with this problem I can try to reproduce it. Also, what is the DPI setting in that screenshot, it looks larger than "normal"?

Comment: I am using the default DPI setting or 125%. Unfortunately, due to this being  a corporate project, I'll not be able to share the complete script.

Comment: You don't have to share a complete script, just a something I can compile that reproduces the problem.